# Ограничить ширину для блока с текстом

Tags: html, css, svg

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 31 31">
      <ellipse rx="14" ry="14" cx="15" cy="16" stroke="rgb(142, 142, 142, 26%)" fill="none" stroke-width="2"></ellipse>
      <text x="15" y="16" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="central" style="font-size: 0.6em;" stroke="22">115%</text>
      <circle cx="18" cy="15" r="14" transform="rotate(-90 17 17)" stroke-width="2" style="stroke-dashoffset: 95px;"></circle>
</svg>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно ограничить максимальную ширину блока с текстом. Чтобы не так близко к краям...

Еще вопрос

```
#Progress {
    fill: none;
    stroke: rgb(255, 0, 0, 42%);
    stroke-dasharray: 100;
    stroke-dashoffset: 100;
    transition: stroke-dasharray 0.5s, stroke-dashoffset 0.5s;
}
.uploads {
    width: 70%;
    max-width: 100px;
    min-width: 30px;
    z-index: 12000;
}

    <svg viewBox="0 0 31 31" class="uploads up1">
         <ellipse rx="14" ry="14" cx="15" cy="16" stroke="rgb(142, 142, 142, 26%)" fill="none" stroke-width="2"></ellipse>
         <text x="15" y="16" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="central" style="font-size: 0.5em; letter-spacing: 1px;">100%</text>
         <circle id="Progress" cx="18" cy="15" r="14" transform="rotate(-90 17 17)" stroke-width="2" style="stroke-dashoffset: 10px;"></circle>
```

Прогресс бару присвоено свойство stroke-dashoffset: 10px;, то есть осталось 10% до полной загрузки. Прогресс бар показывает 100% и так на всем протяжении. То есть он идет на опережение. В чем тут дело?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а  просто размер шрифта уменьшить ? https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/XWNaoKy

Comment: Работает, но как будет со вторым вопросом? 90%, а прогресс бар показывает все 100%

Comment: stroke-dashoffset/stoke-dasgarray наверно не верно посчитан скорее всего

Comment: да и z-index без position не работает ...

Comment: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/VwmzqEK вот так по феншую

Comment: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/vYyJbBZ - это увеличение линии на js + smil

Answer (score 1):

В вашем случае я бы предложил уменьшить межбуквенный интервал, при помощи свойства [`letter-spacing`](http://htmlbook.ru/css/letter-spacing)

```css
.litter {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  border: 4px solid #777;
  font-size: 30px;
  letter-spacing: -5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="litter">100%</div>
```

Ну или изначально подогнать размер шрифта, чтобы при максимальном значение не вылезало.

Comment: Работает, отредактировал пост. Возможно знаете в чем тут дело, прогресс бар идет на опережение. Ближе 100%, он показывает на 10-15 более. То есть уже все 100% при 90%

Comment: @ДмитрийВарзанов, увы, это уже совсем другой вопрос, по этому задайте новый.